# how to turn off hottracking on Delphi ListView?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have a simple ListView on a form and I want to completely turn off hottracking. HotTracking property is set to False but there is still a blue-ish rectangle drawn over the item under the mouse cursor...

Delphi XE3, Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That rectangle is part of the explorer theme. The explorer theme is optional and the list view class elects to use it and imposes it in its `CreateWnd` by calling `SetWindowTheme`. You can override that behaviour by calling `SetWindowTheme` to undo the change.

An example using an interposer class:

```
uses
  Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.UxTheme;

type
  TListView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

procedure TListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowTheme(WindowHandle, nil, nil);
end;
```