# Why only the text is colored, not all the caption of TListView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Sorry, can't comment on [how to turn off hottracking on Delphi ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194320/how-to-turn-off-hottracking-on-delphi-listview), I start a new question.

Following the advice of above link, but when I click on the text of caption, the list shows as follows:

[image]

I have set brush.color in drawItem and drawSubItem of each row:

```
Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := mycolor
```

But If I click on the text of the caption, then in the caption region, only the text part have the colored background.

Code: (Running environment: XE6, Win8.1)

```
TMyTaskListView = class(TListView)
protected
  procedure CreateWnd; override;
end;

procedure TMyTaskListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowTheme(WindowHandle, nil, nil);
end;

var
ListView1: TMyTaskListView;

Form.createForm:

ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'TaskNo';
ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Task1';
ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Task2';
ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Task3';
ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Task Status';
ListView1.Items.Count := 5;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
    Item.Caption := IntToStr(Item.Index);
    Item.SubItems.Add('done');
    Item.SubItems.Add('error'); 
    Item.SubItems.Add('error');
    Item.SubItems.Add('error');
end;

 procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
   Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
 begin

   if lstTaskItemCurClickBackgroundIndex = Item.Index then
         Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $cc;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
   Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
   var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
 begin
   if lstTaskItemCurClickBackgroundIndex = Item.Index then
         Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $cc;
 end;
procedure TForm1.ListView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ARect: TRect;
  Idx: Integer;
  SubItemIndex: Integer;
  pt: TPoint;
  item : TLIstItem;
  hittestinfo: TLVHitTestInfo;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  Idx := -1;
  pt:= ListView1.ScreenToClient( mouse.cursorpos );
  item := ListView1.GetItemAt( pt.x, pt.y );
  If assigned( item ) then
    Idx := item.Index
  else
  begin
    FillChar( hittestinfo, sizeof( hittestinfo ), 0 );
    hittestinfo.pt := pt;
    If -1 <>ListView1.perform( LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, 0, lparam(@hittestinfo))
    Then
    Begin
      Idx := hittestinfo.iItem;
      SubItemIndex := hittestinfo.iSubItem;
    End
    Else
      if (ListView1.Items.Count > 0) then
        Idx := 0;
  end;

  if Idx >= 0 then
  begin
    Rect  := ListView1.Items[Idx].DisplayRect(drBounds);

    if lstTaskItemPrevClickBackgroudColorRect <> Rect then
    begin
      InvalidateRect(ListView1.Handle, lstTaskItemPrevClickBackgroudColorRect, True);
      InvalidateRect(ListView1.Handle, Rect, True);
    end;
    lstTaskItemPrevClickBackgroudColorRect := Rect;
    lstTaskItemCurClickBackgroundIndex := Idx;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you don't post your code, we can't debug it for you. If you want help finding out why your code doesn't work, **post your code** so we can try to answer.

Comment: I posted the code.  I think perhaps there is a special message handled when I clicked on the text of caption. But how to shield this?

Comment: Why are you invalidating rects manually like this? Try using `TListView.UpdateItems()` instead. It invalidates items for you. Or better yet, don't even invalidate the items manually at all. Clicking an item triggers repaints automatically.

Comment: It would have been really easy to make an mcve

Comment: @Remy   I changed InvalidateRect to TListView.UpdateItems(), but the result is the same.  When I click over other place than the text of caption, all the row is red background;  but when I click over the text of caption, only that text has red background.

Comment: @coo: Sorry, but I am not able to reproduce the problem in XE2 using the code you have shown. The entire cell is painted, as expected.

Comment: @Remy  My environment is XE6. I create the exe in Win8.1.  And when I transfer the exe to XP, the problem also exists.

Comment: I dont know if I said clearly, I meaned to click over the text of caption, i.e. the text of the first cell of each row, not the other place of the row.

Comment: @coo: "My environment is XE6", that is important information that should have been provided up front.